# 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope

Tags: serial, arduino-uno

Trying to do serial communication between 2 Arduino Unos.

Code:

```c++
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int ledPin = 13;
int board;   // 1 = Uno. 2 = Mega.
int on_off;  // 1 = On. 0 = Off.
int buzzerPin = 9;
int Ack_tx = 2; //Acknowledgement tx.
int rec;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);      // start serial communication at 9600bps
  Serial1.begin(9600);     // start serial1 communication at 9600bps

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.flush();
  Serial1.flush();

} // End Setup

void loop()
{

  Serial.println("Enter Uno=1/Mega=0 ...");  //Select board
  //  if(!Serial){ board = Serial.read();}
  while(Serial.available()==0) { // Wait for User to Input Data
  }
  board = Serial.parseInt();  //Read the data the user has input


  Serial.println("Enter LED On=1/Off=0 ...");  //Select On or Off
  while (Serial.available()==0) { // Wait for User to Input Data
  }
  on_off = Serial.parseInt();

  Serial.println();


  switch (board) {

  case 0:  //Mega board
    if (on_off == 1) digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); //Select Uno LED On
    else digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);              //Select Uno LED Off
    break;  //End Case

  case 1:  //Uno board
    //Serial.println("Off to Uno...");
    //Send on_off info to Uno
    Serial1.write(on_off/256); //Send the Quotient or "how many times" value
    Serial1.write(on_off%256); //Send the Modulo or Remainder.
    delay(50); //Wait for the serial port.

    while(Serial1.available()<2) //Wait for 2 bytes to arrive
     {
      //do nothing
     } //End While


  byte b1=Serial1.read();  //Read Upper byte
  byte b2=Serial1.read();  //Read Lower byte
  rec=(b1*256)+b2; 

    if (rec == Ack_tx) tone(buzzerPin, 300, 300); //Ack_tx from Uno
    break;
  } //End Switch Case

}
```

Error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\Akshit\Documents\Arduino\sketch_mar06a\sketch_mar06a.ino: In function 'void setup()':

sketch_mar06a:13: error: 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope

   Serial1.begin(9600);     // start serial1 communication at 9600bps

   ^

C:\Users\Akshit\Documents\Arduino\sketch_mar06a\sketch_mar06a.ino: In function 'void loop()':

sketch_mar06a:51: error: 'Serial1' was not declared in this scope

     Serial1.write(on_off/256); //Send the Quotient or "how many times" value

     ^

Multiple libraries were found for "SoftwareSerial.h"
 Used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SoftwareSerial
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial
exit status 1
'Serial1' was not declared in this scope

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

This is a very basic problem I know, but nothing on the internet is helping.

Comment: Why do you think "Serial1" should exist?

Comment: I picked this code off of the internet.
I feel it should exist because we would need one serial for communication with the serial monitor of computer 
and a second one for the actual serial communication between the two arduinos
Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So... you saw it in random code and thought it would work everywhere?

Comment: The code made sense to me. Couldnt think of any changes to make.. 
Ill try the answer given by Majenko

Comment: @Aki An Uno has only one hardware serial interface (`Serial`). What do you expect `Serial1` to be?

Comment: @gre_gor read my 1st comment. I am an extreme noob at this..

Answer (score 10):

The Uno has no `Serial1`. It only has one serial port, called `Serial`. To use `Serial1` you will need a bigger board such as a Mega2560, or define it as a `SoftwareSerial` port and use two other IO pins of your choice for it, though at lower baud rates than `Serial` can run at.

Comment: I have arduino micro, and I can use serial (form comunication pc )and serial1 (form com. wifi module).

Answer (score 7):

You import the `SoftwareSerial` library but you however never instance an object of the `SoftwareSerial` class.

You just need to add the line

```
 SoftwareSerial Serial1(10, 11); // RX, TX
```

after including the library header (taken from [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample))

This now creates an object `Serial1` on which the operations down there should work the same as with a real hardware serial (API-wise).

Side note: Careful with the wiring. You are using this `Serial1` emulated UART to communicate between the boards, so if you're using above pin numbers (D10 = RX, D11 =TX) then you must connected D10 (Board1) -> D11 (Board2), D11 (Board1) -> D10 (Board2), i.e. RX->TX, TX->RX.